# Google Chrome Extension How to wait for page to be loaded completely (loading screen)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension is trying to use CSS selectors on pages to grab certain elements. I am running into an issue where on websites that load abnormally/ continuously load elements after it's changeInfo.status is already "complete" when my script is executed, it doesn't grab info from sections that haven't loaded. An example of this are websites with loading screens and websites with multiple frames.  A possible solution would be for the user to click a button to execute the script, but I was wondering if there was alternate way to tell my script to wait for the page to fully load so it can automatically pull the information. I would like an alternate solution than setting allFrames to true because it doesn't work for all websites with this issue, nor do I find it necessary for my script to run on every frame it encounters. I have also tried waiting for the load event, but that did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Because the load event will fire before the dynamic content loads, you wont be able to use that. If you don't have a hook into the content loading and want something more "automated", you could use a recursive timeout function and check periodically for the desired content to load and act when the content is present.

```js
function timeoutFunction() {
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("checkThis").value;
  console.log(inputVal);
  if (inputVal !== "STOP") {
    setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 3000);
    console.log("Keyword not found.");
  } else {
    console.log("Keyword found.");
  }
}

$(function(){setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 3000)});
```

```html
<span>The function will check every three seconds for the value of this input to be "STOP"</span>
<input id="checkThis">
```

Comment: I am using vanilla javascript, but I understand the logic. Is there a way that doesn't involve constantly checking for the information? Because there are some values that will consistently not be on most webpages and it seems strange to have it run indefinitely. If there isn't I believe I could just add a counter for timeouts and have it end after a certain number of timeouts.

Comment: It doesn't run indefinitely. Once the information you are looking for has loaded, the recursive process stops.

Comment: It would if it can't find the information right? What I was trying to say is that even if the page is fully loaded, sometimes the information I'm looking for won't be there.

Comment: Yes, that's why in the example I provided the timer will run only if the desired content isn't present. Once the desired content appears, the process ends.